# Python webscraping to files that have a different name each time

Tags: python, web-scraping

I created a program where each day my program scrapes a particular pages although I can't find a function that would allow me to save the data to a new file with a different name each day. Ex: test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4, test 5.

Comment: You could perhaps add a [timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time_ns) to your filename, if you do not care too much about the actual number (other than it being unique for each time your program runs).

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would be, that you create a separate counter file. With this approach you would just get the counter value each time your script runs, name your new file accordingly and save the increased counter value in the file.

One tutorial for python file handling: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp

There's probably a more elegant solution, but I couldn't think of any other just now.

Hope I could help ;)